# g++ has unreferenced function error with lib

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

The project has three files, main.c, file1.c and file2.c

```
gcc -o main.o -c main.c
gcc -o file1.o -c file1.c
gcc -o file2.o -c file2.c
```

Method 1, works well

```
g++ -o main.exe main.o file1.o file2.o
```

Method 2, failed

```
ar rv lib.a file1.o file2.o
g++ -o main.exe lib.a main.o
```

```
main.c:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `ini_load'
```

Anything wrong in the commands? Thx

Answer (score 2):

The position in the command line *matters.*

When you list a library on the command line, it's used to satisfy unresolved references in existence *at that time.* From the `gcc` man-page:

> It makes a difference where in the command you write this option; the linker searches and processes libraries and object files in the order they are specified. Thus, `foo.o -lz bar.o` searches library `z` *after* file `foo.o` but *before* `bar.o`. If `bar.o` refers to functions in `z`, those functions may not be loaded.

If you change it to:

```
g++ -o main.exe main.o lib.a
```

then it should work fine, as all the unresolved references in `mian.o` will be searched for in the objects within `lib.a`.

Comment: Thanks! It rocks. And another question, if there are more than one libs, dose the order also matter?

Comment: @Tmx, yes, it does, if `lib1.a` has symbols that can only be satisfied by `lib2.a`, then the order has to be `lib1 lib2`. If there are _circular_ references, you're in for a world of pain :-) You can do it, but it involves listing libraries more than once, such as `lib1 lib2 lib1`. You're wise to avoid circular references if you can, trust me.